# Get first child in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to get and modify the first child of the given element in an Angular directive.

```
<div class="wanted">
</div>
<div class="not-wanted">
</div>
<div class="not-wanted">
</div>
```

I already tried

```
elm.children('.wanted')
```

but then my directive modifies all children.
How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Did you give a try with css :first child selector

Comment: update the question with more codes

Comment: JqLite does not accept a selector for children() - so that is why you are getting all the direct child elements. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Answer (score 9):

You can either use:

```
elm.children().first();
```

or:

```
elm.children(':first')
```

Both will have the same effect. The second one is slightly more performant.

Comment: I got TypeError: elm.children(...).first is not a function for the first one

Comment: Could you update your question with your directive source and the way you use it in your html?

Comment: In AngularJS (jqlite) children doesn't support selectors, that's jQuery. AngularJS doesn't support first() either, that's also jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

Angular includes jqLite. JqLite does not accept a selector for [children()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) - so that is why you are getting all the direct child elements.

`element.children()` - Does not support selectors

Comment: Angular jqLite doesn't accept a class selector for find either. "Limited to lookups by tag name".

Answer (score 5):

I use: `element.children().eq(0)`

`children()` - Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements

`eq()` - Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index

Answer (score 1):

In angular way with the help of Directives

```
<div ng-repeat="name in names">
<div check-render>{{name}}</div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('checkRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
if(scope.$first)
alert('first called');
}
}
});
```

Comment: This makes no sense.  Your attribute is `custom-render`, but your directive is bound to `checkRender`.  Also, to have to write an entire controller / directive just to determine if the first child exists?  Doesn't seem like it's the best way.